# MySQL: Is it possible to do this with a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform two different SUMs within a single query.

```
user   points   date_achieved
-----------------------------
Foo    10       2000-01-01
Foo    20       2011-11-18
Bar    10       2000-01-01
Bar    20       2011-11-15
Bar    30       2011-11-18
```

1) Total points

```
SELECT user, SUM(points) AS points_total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY user
```

2) Points accumulated within the past month

```
SELECT user, SUM(points) AS points_month
FROM myTable
WHERE date_achieved >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY user
```

What is the best way to achieve this with a single query?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a case statement to only count points when it meets your criteria.

```
SELECT 
       user, 
        SUM(points) AS points,
        SUM(case  
            when date_achieved >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
            THEN points 
             else 0 END) points_last_Month
FROM myTable
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    user,
    sum(points) as points_total,
    sum(
        case
            when date_achieved >= current_date - interval 1 month then points
            else 0
        end
    ) as points_month
from myTable
group by user
```